# Unable to find rss feed URL in few websites

Tags: rss

I want to make a tech news app in android by parsing rss feed from various tech websites, I have found techcrunch rss feed URL by looking for href in page source using type="application/rss+xml".

RSS feed URL of techcrunch: 
     http://techcrunch.com/feed/

I'm unable to find similar URLs for other websites like cnet, gizmodo etc.

Is there any other way of finding rss feed URLs ?

Answer (score 3):

While on the homepage, http://techcrunch.com/ for you, press ctrl+u and the source code appears. There press ctrl+f and try searching for stuff like rss, atom, feed... Works for me in Firefox (not sure if ctrl+u has different compilation in Chrome for example).

If that's a slow approach for you, try installing an add-on like Feedbro, open the site on a tab and from the icon of Feedbro click "Find feeds on Current Tab", and then go to the add-on to see the details on the feed.

Answer (score 0):

Some sites use ATOM, rather than RSS, feeds. Some websites will not even specify the RSS link in the head tag. You will have to leave it to the user to find the RSS link and let him add it to your app.